# Rewrite/Forward URL in both directions ends in loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewrite or forward two URLs in both directions, because the software used does not allow this change in the called URL.

The URL that is called is "https://example.com/customerarea/cart.php?a=view" and should be forwarded to https://example.com/cart/ which is rewritten to the called URL.

Rewrite "cart/" to "customerarea/cart.php?a=view":

```
RewriteRule ^cart/$ customerarea/cart.php?a=view [QSA,L]
```

This rule works.

If I add the following condition and rule to forward from "customerarea/cart.php?a=view" to "cart/", it ends in a continuous loop.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/customerarea/cart.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/cart/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+customerarea/cart\.php\?a=view [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cart/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cart/$ /customerarea/cart.php?a=view [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Can you explain the first condition and rule, especially why a space can be so important?

Comment: In first rule space is not important but use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` is important which doesn't change its value after execution of rewrite rules.

Comment: And why is the space in the second rule so important? That's what I meant.

Comment: There is `\s/` in 1st rule that checks its presence `%{THE_REQUEST}` is that you're asking?

Comment: No, i meant the space in the second rule, between ^ and /cart/?. Without that space it ends in a continuous loop, with the space it works great. That's why I am surprised why a space is so important.

Comment: That space is not for matching for syntax. That rule is just matching `^` which in regex means line start (always true). And that is not 2nd rule that is first rule. I suggest you do some reading on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Oops, right, I haven't looked closely enough. Thank you again!